# Find the equation of the locus of a point which has its sum of distance from (0,3) and (0,-3) equal to 8.

Tags: coordinate-systems

I know the answer but due to various expressions under root, I'm unable to reach there. 
Is there something which I'm missing to make the solution easier? By the way the answer given is $$\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{y^2}{7}=1$$ which isn't equal to the one I'm getting, in fact, it is nowhere close to it.

---

My answer: (I just used the one plane distance formula here)$$30y^2+64^2+12(64)y=16^2•(x^2+y^2)+16^2(9+6y)$$
I see no point in expanding this.

Comment: I think the standard equation of ellipse as you have given has centre (0, 0) whereas according to your given points the centre is not the origin so I don't think the answer should be in that form.

Comment: Okay..$$\text{ }$$

Comment: Hey I am not quite sure, please verify it.

Comment: Yeah that's fine. Thanks for the reply anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start from
$$\sqrt{x^2+(y+3)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y-3)^2}=8.$$
Bring $\sqrt{x^2+(y-3)^2}$ to the other side and square. We get
$$x^2+(y+3)^2=64-16\sqrt{x^2+(y-3)^2}+x^2+(y-3)^2.$$
A little algebra brings us to 
$$12y-64=-16\sqrt{x^2+(y-3)^2}.$$
Minor cancellation gives
$$4\sqrt{x^2+(y-3)^2}=16-3y.$$
Square. We get some cancellation and arrive at
$$16x^2+7y^2=16^2-(16)(9)=(16)(7).$$
Finally, divide both sides by $(16)(7)$.

**Remark:** You may find it easier to deal with the slightly more general equation
$$\sqrt{x^2+(y+p)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y-p)^2}=k.$$
The steps are exactly the same, but we don't get the distraction of numbers. I certainly find it easier!

Comment: Note: this answer assumes the foci to be $(3,0)$ and $(-3,0)$, which seems right but contrary to the question statement.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thank you, I misread $(0,-3)$ and $(0,3)$ as the more standard $(-3,0), (3,0)$. I have changed the answer by interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$, I hope everywhere.

Comment: You are welcome. Do try it with symbols, it may feel simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The center of an ellipse is always the midpoint of the foci, so this ellipse must be centered at the origin.

In addition, the line on which the foci fall is always the major axis, while the perpendicular line is the $y$-axis.  In this case, these are the $y$ and $x$ axis respectively.

So, we now know that the ellipse has the equation
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1
$$
Where $a$ is half the minor axis, i.e. the $x$-intercept and $b$ is half the major axis, i.e. the $y$-intercept.

We can now figure out the equation for the ellipse by noting that both $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ must be on the ellipse.  In particular, we have
$$
\sqrt{a^2 + 3^2} + \sqrt{a^2 + 3^2} = 8\\
(b-3) + (b + 3) = 8 
$$

Comment: +1 Thanks Omnomnomnom (I wonder what made you create an account with that name, it was difficult for me to type). :)

Comment: Thanks for the introduction of ellipse(s). It is still to be covered in my institute.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate the arrival of last two equations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HarshalGajjar I'm noting that the sum of the distance from an axis-intercept to each of the foci